# how to create a view and insert data into it

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to insert data into above tables with below conditions:

- conditional & dynamic
- automated transaction behavior using triggers

Create a view to include a join of relevant queries then define a
   trigger on the view then define a sp to insert data into the view

Comment: Do not post in all caps. Add DDL for the table and view along with what you've tried.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT! Or fix your keyboard. And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: improved formatting